What does "behaving like independent random variables" mean?
The following is from Gonek's paper:

The situation is much more interesting if the Riemann hypothesis holds. In that case we may rewrite (6) as $$ \sum_{0 < γ \le T} x^{iγ} « Tx^{-1/2+ Ɛ} + x^{1/2+ Ɛ}, \ \ \ \   (x,T>2)$$  The left-hand side is trivially $ O(TlogT)$ , so the second term on the right is nontrivial (roughly) in the range $2 \le x \le T^{2-Ɛ}$. Now if the terms $x^{iγ}$ behave like independent random variables, we might expect that $$ \sum_{0 < γ \le T} x^{iγ} « T^{1/2+ Ɛ},$$ for almost all positive x.

My questions is how is $ \sum_{0 < γ \le T} x^{iγ} « T^{1/2+ Ɛ}$ true? I don't know what does the author mean by "to behave like independent random variables" but if it means that $x^{iγ} = e^{iγ \log x}$ take random values then the sum in the question must be zero since sum of equally distributed numbers on the circle $|z|=1$ is zero.

two random variables $X$ and $Y$ behave like independent variables iff $P(X) \approx P(X|Y)$
